# Delphi - Indy 10 #10600 Connection Timeout with POST over 32767 bytes

Tags: delphi, http, post, indy

I'm having a persistent problem using Indy 10 where I am posting a string of XML encoded as a `TIdMultiPartFormDataStream`, the code that I am using to invoke the POST is given below. A majority of the time, this works no problem, however I am getting a repeated error when running on Windows 7 that throws a #10060 Connection Timeout socket error only when the XML string is longer than 32767 bytes, anything under that size works without a problem.

I have verified that it is not related to the server I am posting to, as there is no problem for messages of any size sent with the same code/application on Windows XP.

```
IdHTTP2 := TIdHTTP.Create();

UsingHTTPS := (Pos(LowerCase('https://'), Trim(LowerCase(URL)))> 0);
if UsingHTTPS then begin
IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL2:=TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create();
  with IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL2 do
  begin
    SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;
    SSLOptions.Mode := sslmUnassigned;
    SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [];
    SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 0;
    Port := 443;
  end;
 end; //if UsingHTTPS


try
  try
    with IdHTTP2 do
    begin //with some browser style defaults
      AllowCookies := False;
      ProxyParams.BasicAuthentication := False;
      //ProxyParams.ProxyPort := 0;
      Request.ContentLength := data.Size;
      Request.host := '';
      Request.CustomHeaders.Clear;
      Request.Accept := '';
      Request.ContentEncoding := '';
      IOHandler:=IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL2;
      ReadTimeout := -1;
    end;


     //http post
    IdHTTP2.Post(URL, data, response);
```

Does anyone have any recommendations to solve this problem? I tried to set the `ReadTimeout` variable but this had no change. Any pointers to solve this problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is there a difference in the MTU size between the two clients? If the code works on XP but not on 7 maybe there's some environmental issue.

Comment: I generally don't set the content length and let the component calculate the size. Also, consider enabling `sslvrfPeer` mode in the SSL `VerifyMode` options, otherwise the server certificate isn't validated, and you're wide open to man-in-the-middle attacks.

Comment: Use a packet sniffer, such as Wireshark, to make sure data is actually being transmitted back and forth in a timely manner. Or at least look at the call stack when the exception is raised to see if the timeout is occurring during the SSL handshake, while sending the request, or while receiving the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` sets a hard-coded 30 second read/write timeout on an SSL socket on Windows Vista+ when the `ReadTimeout` property is <= 0, so chances are the connection is slow enough to take longer than 30 seconds to transmit data.  Try setting the `ReadTimeout` property to a higher value to see if it delays the error.  If so, then there really is a transmission issue.

You can use a packet sniffer, such as Wireshark, to make sure data is actually being transmitted back and forth in a timely manner. Also look at the call stack when the exception is raised to see if the timeout is occurring during the SSL handshake, while sending the HTTP request, or while receiving the HTTP response.  That will help determine whether it is an issue with OpenSSL, Indy, or the server.

Comment: Hi Remy, thanks for the advice. The request and response seemed to be arriving in a reasonable time, but I was able to step through the code and found that it was throwing a exception because the connection was closed gracefully by the server after sending a 200 header while the client was waiting to read a non-existent response body. Using the Post method without passing a response stream fixes the issue.

Comment: `TIdHTTP` reads a response body if a response body is actually expected. For a `POST` request, no body is present if there is a `Content-Length: 0` response header and no `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` response header, or if the `Content-Length` header is missing and the server closes the connection after the headers. Any other combination requires a response body to be present. `TIdHTTP` recognizes and handles those conditions.

Comment: As for discarding data, if you pass a `nil` response stream, `TIdHTTP` will still read the response body, if there is one, but it will discard whatever body reads. On the other hand, if you do not pass a response stream at all (`nil` or otherwise), then you will be calling the overloaded version of `Post()` that returns a `String`, so `TIdHTTP` will still read a response body, if there is one, and you will be the one discarding data, not `TIdHTTP`.